# Como fazer um filtro com != ou IsNotIqualTo no Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firestore

Olá!

Estou precisando fazer uma consulta com filtro na `firestore` porém li na documentação que não possuem "!=" ou "IsNotIqualTo" para criar uma restrição. Queria fazer algo como:

Buscar livros que não estejam cadastrados com o email do usuário.

```
var snapshots = Firestore.instance
    .collection('livros')
    .where('email', isNotEqualTo: _email )
    .snapshots();
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: não é possível segundo documentação, segue: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=pt-br#query_limitations

Answer (score 0):

Agora é possivel utilizar a query "not equal" no firestore.
basicamente use `collection('colecao').where('campo', '!=', 'valor');`

leia mais em: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html

Answer (score -1):

Basta utilizar:

```
var snapshots = Firestore.instance
.collection('livros')
.where('email', '!=', _email )
.snapshots();
```

Comment: Seria bom explicar as diferenças do seu código para o que foi perguntado.